# How, where and when does Magento 2 save customer Tax/Vat number to the order?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, tax, vat

I can not understand why the `customer_taxvat` field in `sales_order` table is empty for customers who have Tax/VAT number.

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be explained by the fact that there are two different places where customer can add an VAT number. Customer address has a VAT ID field that is stored to the vat_id field in customer_address_entity table.

Customer entity on the other hand has a different Tax/Vat field that is used for example when customer is registering and he is put to certain customer group. This is stored in the taxvat field in customer_entity table.

It is a bit confusing for customers that is for sure.